# Ordinary Differential Equation how to solve this

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi i need to learn in fast way how to solve ode i still have problem with this.
I need to find $y = y(x)$
having
$y′ = 0$,
$y′′ = 0$, 
$y′′′ = 0$,
$y'''' = 0$

I am guessing that $y= e^{rx}$ Then we have some function with degree of 4 but how to solve this. I am not even sure that my guess is correct xD.
I think we can write $a_0y+ a_1y' + a_2y''+a_3y'''+a_4y''' =0$.
It looks maybe simple but i dont knew how to solve this. I probably need to use some high mathematical knowledge. When my knowledge about maths end on simple integrals and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y' = 0 \iff y = C, C$ constant.

Remember that for y = y(x), y' means the rate of change of y with respect to x. In other words, as you increase or decrease x, how does y change? If y' is 0 it means there's no change in y as you increase or decrease x, which means y has a constant value. To find out the value of C, you'd need further information e.g. an initial condition such as $y(0) = 4$, for which the solution is clearly $y = 4$.

Comment: but how do you have y''= 0 when y' =0?

Comment: It's the only possible value. The differential of any constant (including 0) is 0.

Comment: ok thx. I forgot that 0 is const xD

Comment: no problems @Luffy

Comment: Consider displacement = $\frac {d}{dt}$ (speed) = $\frac {d}{dt} (\frac {d}{dt}$ (acceleration)). If speed is $0$, displacement will also be $0$, which is why when a car's speed is 0, it doesn't move anywhere. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. With a homogeneous equation and homogeneous boundary conditions only the trivial solution (given above as y=C) is possible...

Paul Safier